# how to center text AND have max width of 800px in CSS?

Tags: html, css, text, alignment, center

I'm trying to center a block of text on a page while maintaining the maximum width of 800px. How do I do this? Here is my code:

```
#footer {
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #47a7d3;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#terms {
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-bottom: -0.75em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: the issue was that the terms were not centering on the footer sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

Define your `#footer` `id` `left:0;` `right:0;` remove `with:100%;`

Define your `#terms`  `margin-left: auto;`  `margin-right:auto;` as like this

**css**

```
#footer {
        text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #47a7d3;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding:0;
}

#terms {
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-bottom: -0.75em;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4uvBL/)**

Answer (score 0):

here is a jsfiddle.

I added a max-wdith to keep max width at 800px
I added a margin 0 auto to center div
I added a align-text center, doing this and adding the p tag to the #terms id will keep the text in

centered

Working JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/fMyLz/

CSS:

```
footer h1{
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #47a7d3;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
}

#terms p  {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #000;
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="terms">
    <p>hey whast up this works man! hey whast up this works man! hey whast up this works man! hey whast up this works man! hey whast up this works man! hey whast up this works man! hey whast up this works man!</p>
</div>

<footer>
    <h1> This is the footer </h1>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that #terms is inside of the #footer, you can try adding "display: inline-block;" inside of #terms. Since you have "text-align: center;" set on footer, adding "display: inline-block;" to the terms element will cause it to be treated like text and it should be centered.... but more information and HTML code would be a lot more helpful in providing a solution to your problem.